# Existence of enough projectives in the category of sets

Tags: axiom-of-choice, ct.category-theory

I am talking about the principle that says that every set is the image of a [projective](http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&id=6437) set. For every set $x$ there is a surjection $f:y \twoheadrightarrow x$, such that for any set $u$ and function $j:y \to u$ and surjection $g:v \twoheadrightarrow u$ there is a function $h:y \to v$ such that $j=gh$.

There is a simple model of CZF in which this holds and the axiom of choice is violated. This also violates classical logic so is not a model of ZF (= CZF + classical logic). I am curious about the following comment of Andreas Blass on ZF:

> ...all the usual independence results involving weak axioms of choice remain true in
>   the presence of the negation of EPSets. In particular, none of the axioms in the 
>   appendix of [Jech, the Axiom of Choice], except AC itself, implies EPSets. 
>   The following result ... is essentially all that is known about the strength of EPSets...
>
> Theorem 6.2 EPSets implies the axiom of dependent choice ...
>
> In particular, we do not know whether it implies AC ... we conjecture that it does not.

(Injectivity, Projectivity, and the Axiom of Choice, 1979)

[Consequence of the Axiom of Choice](http://consequences.emich.edu/CONSEQ.HTM) (1998) listed the question of whether it implies AC as still open, and in fact unless I missed something it listed no new non-trivial results.

So, in 2010, is there really still nothing to be said other than ZF+DC < ZF+EPSets $\le$ ZFC ?

Comment: Where do you get "ZF+DC ≠ ZF+EPSets"?

Comment: Sorry, it's also in Blass' article, I added a bit more context.

Comment: I thought David McCarty's model of IZF satisfies the presentation axiom but not choice. Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, but it's also a model of ECT_0 (violates classical logic), so not of ZF.

Comment: For reference, it is form 192 at the linked website.

Comment: The link to `planetmath.org` is broken, but a copy is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509213143/http://planetmath.org/projectiveobject). The link to `consequences.emich.edu` is also broken, but the new version of the site can be found at [Choiceless Grapher](https://cgraph.inters.co/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard any new information about "enough projective sets" in the classical ZF context.  Your formulation, however, looks weaker.  "Enough projective sets" should say that for every $x$ there is a surjection $f:y \to x$ such that every surjection from any $w$ to $y$ splits.  That implies your formulation (by taking $w$ to be the pullback of $y$ and $z$ over $x$) but I don't see the converse.

The principle "enough projective sets" has been used in constructive mathematics by Peter Aczel (and probably others) under the name "presentation axiom".

Comment: The presentation axiom (projective set = "base") is how I heard of it, and the weaker formulation was just carelessness on my part, I changed it.